# FireBase multiple queries by document and collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling with firebase to run one query to take the truckDocumentId and after that to run another query to take the routesByDateDocumentIdand at the end I am using both document ids to run the function "sendGpsPosition", my problem is that the first query finds truckDocumentId but sometimes the second query does not execute and that is why the applications stops. The code below is for Kotlin.

If I am on Debug then most of the time works.. if I switch off the debug it almost shows the error below =>

And because the query does not execute I got this error: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but trucks has 1*

```
suspend fun getTruckId() {
    val trucksReference = firestore.collection("trucks").whereEqualTo("dispatcher", "Miro")
        .whereEqualTo("name", "PEUGEOT").get().await()
    val document = trucksReference.documents[0]
    if (document != null) {
        truckDocumentId = document.id
    }
}

suspend fun getRouteReferenceId() {
    val routesByDate = firestore.collection("trucks")
        .document(truckDocumentId)
        .collection("routes_by_date").get().await()
    val documentRoute = routesByDate.documents[0]
    if (documentRoute != null) {
        routesByDateDocumentId = documentRoute.id
    }
}


fun sendGpsPosition(lat: Double, long: Double, imageRef: String? = null) {
    runBlocking { getTruckId() } // if I get this DocumentID
    runBlocking { getRouteReferenceId() } // this here maybe will be not found or maybe will be found.. the async is not done correct not sure how to do it.
    firestore
        .collection("trucks")
        .document(truckDocumentId)
        .collection("routes_by_date")
        .document(routesByDateDocumentId)
        .collection("live_route")
        .add(LatLong(Timestamp.now(), lat, long))
}
```

Comment: Instead of showing variables whose values we can't see, hard code all of the document and collection strings and show that code.  Or, show us the values of all the variables that lead to this error.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is that sometimes I find the documentId with the first query but the second does not find it... and it crashes.. if I debug it is ok, I need to do it "async" somehow with Coroutines ... but I cant make it works I changed the code but still does not work

Comment: Check it now, I  updated the code

Comment: We still can't see the values of the variables you're using in the query.  You should log them to make sure they are what you expect just before you use them.

Comment: the default values are: var routesByDateDocumentId = ""
        var truckDocumentId = ""   so if I dont get anything from firebase I put "" and because of this is crashing..  somehow the process does not wait the 1 process to finish, sorry first day with Android Kotlin, .... :D my boss told me to fix something and it is not very similar to what I am used to work with

Comment: Normally I am using auto generated code like that for both variables "LVgjG7GAMujF42mCERs3"

Comment: Yes, you will have to do something to make sure your query only executes after you have valid values for the collection and document.  You can't use an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 **I solved it this way.**

private suspend fun getTruckId() {
            val trucksReference = firestore.collection("trucks")
                .whereEqualTo("dispatcher", "Miro")
                .whereEqualTo("name", "VW")
                .get()
                .await()
            val document = trucksReference.documents[0]
            if (document != null) {
                truckDocumentId = document.id
            }
        }
    
        private suspend fun getRouteReferenceId() {
            val currentTime = Timestamp.now()
            val routesByDate = firestore.collection("trucks")
                .document(truckDocumentId)
                .collection("routes_by_date")
                .get()
                .await() // here will be better to look for data by delivery_day
            val documentRoute = routesByDate.documents[0]
            if (documentRoute != null) {
                routesByDateDocumentId = documentRoute.documents[0].id
            }
        }
    
        private fun addGpsDataInDatabase(lat: Double, long: Double, imageRef: String? = null) {
            firestore
                .collection("trucks")
                .document(truckDocumentId)
                .collection("routes_by_date")
                .document(routesByDateDocumentId)
                .collection("planned_route")  //planned_route or live_route depends if we want to show current state of a truck of make a route plan
                .add(LatLong(Timestamp.now(), lat, long))
        }
    
        fun sendGpsPosition(lat: Double, long: Double, imageRef: String? = null) {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                val truckDocId = async { getTruckId() }
                truckDocId.await()
                val routeDocId = async { getRouteReferenceId() }
                routeDocId.await()
                addGpsDataInDatabase(lat, long, imageRef)
            }
    
        }
```